# WPF How can I control height of RibbonTab?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

[image: enter image description here 1]

[image: enter image description here 2]

I use the RibbonControl in WPF but I can't change RibbonTab Height.

I want to control the height of the section marked with the red arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Ribbon have fixed height so you cant change it. The ribbon control dynamically resizes as the width of the application window changes

You can bind the heights of `RibbonTabs` and `RibbonGroups` to your windows and tabs so that they have same size.

Read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701790(v=vs.110).aspx) for more